# Fit and predict logistic regression model for censored data?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, censoring

Suppose I have a data frame such that:

```
set.seed(2014)
df<-data.frame(y=rbinom(100,1,0.3),futime=as.integer(rnorm(100,100,10)),
     age=rnorm(100,50,5),sex=rbinom(100,1,0.5))
df[df>100]<-100
```

where `y` is the outcomes and `futime<100` are right censored of follow up time. I would fit a logistic regression model to predict the outcomes as if they are not censored. I saw there are some options such as `tobit` model, `survival` model and `censReg` package, but seems not very similar situation. Would somebody know the best way for this using `age` and `sex` as predictors?

Comment: What does it mean that follow-up time is right censored?  In the data your code generates, futime is 104 for observation 1 before the right censoring and 100 after the right censoring.  Does that mean that Y was truly measured at a follow-up time of 104 but the data record a value of 100 for it?  Also, why is follow-up time important?  Does Y change over time?